# Tag do HTML não aparecem

Tags: php, html, html5

faço uma consulta em uma tabela determinada e o resultado é o seguinte:

```
<p><span style="font-size:14px;"><strong><span style="color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">texto texto</span></strong></span></p>
```

Ate ai tudo bem mas quando coloco um echo $dados3['description'] que tem esse resultado acima ele escreve exatamente como colei acima, ele não formata.

quero que ai executar a pagina ele use essas tag html como salvo no banco, mas caso não for possível como posso fazer para eliminar todo restante e deixar só o texto puro?

Comment: Se usar `echo strip_tags($dados3['description']);` vai imprimir apenas o texto.

Comment: Sim ja havia usado mas parece que ele ignora esse comando a saída é igual ai que descrevi acima, muito estranho.

Comment: Acho que vc poderia colocar mais informações na pergunta. Coloca um print de como aparece no banco de dados e como aparece no inspecionar elementos do navegador, além de como está fazendo esse `echo` no HTML. Esse problema pode ser por causa de mts coisas, e só com essa informação na pergunta fica difícil de dar qualquer resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar a função nativa do PHP `html_entity_decode();`

```
$result = '&#60;br&#62;';

echo $result; // <br>
```

Em vez disso, use:

```
echo html_entity_decode($result) // Então navegador irá interpretar esse código
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a pergunta:

No banco de dados esta gravado dessa maneira:

```
&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;Produto feito 100% Artesanalmente com todo carinho e dedicação que as artesãs merecem.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;Além de um item super útil para seu ateliê, pela sua elegância e sofisticação também é uma peça de decoração para o seu ateliê.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;Produto Exclusivo do Ateliê Cris Ramos.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;Obs.: Alfinetes não estão incluídos&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &amp;quot;Open Sans&amp;quot;, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;font color=&quot;#ff0000&quot; face=&quot;Arial Black&quot;&gt;Este produto pode ser trocado por 500 pontos do programa de fidelidade&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

O Campo no mysql é:
Nome Campo    Tipo     Colação
description   text     utf8_general_ci

A Busca em php que faço é simples:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT `description` FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE `product_id` = '5'";
$query3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
while ($dados3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
  $descricao = strip_tags($dados3['description']);
}
```

Ao dar o echo o resultado é esse:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Produto feito 100% Artesanalmente com todo carinho e dedicação que as artesãs merecem.</strong></span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Além de um item super útil para seu ateliê, pela sua elegância e sofisticação também é uma peça de decoração para o seu ateliê.</strong></span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><strong style="color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Produto Exclusivo do Ateliê Cris Ramos.</strong><br></p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Obs.: Alfinetes não estão incluídos</strong></span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><br></strong></span></p><p style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 12px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; line-height: 20px; color: rgb(97, 11, 90); font-family: Acme; font-size: 14px;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><strong style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><font color="#ff0000" face="Arial Black">Este produto pode ser trocado por 500 pontos do programa de fidelidade</font></strong><br></strong></span></p>
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com o html_entity_decode, em vez de usar o strip_tags usei o html_entity_decode e funcionou, alguém havia respondido mas acabou apagando a resposta , agradeço a essa pessoa que acabei não conseguindo ver o nome.